# Toggle values in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

My table has a column named `status` with data type `CHARACTER`. I wish to do the following.

> If a row does not exists for a primary key, insert 'active' in
>   `status`.   If a row already has an entry for a primary key, toggle
>   the `status`. Use `ative`, `not_active` values for toggling.

Currently I am doing it by writing multiple queries. Is there any single query to do this like Mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not have control logic commands like `IF` because that would not make sense in an embedded database.

Implement the control logic in whatever language you're using to access the database:

```py
db.begin_transaction()
result = db.execute("SELECT status FROM MyTable WHERE id = ?", [id]);
if result.length > 0:
    new_status = if result[0][0] == 'active': 'not_active' else: 'active'
    db.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET status = ? WHERE id = ?", [new_status, id])
else:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable(id, status) VALUES(?, ?)", [id, 'active'])
db.commit()
```

However, the toggle logic itself can be implemented with a [`CASE` expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case), so if you don't care too much about clarity, you can execute the following two commands instead, in this order (the `UPDATE` will do nothing if the record does not exist, and the [`INSERT OR IGNORE`](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) will do nothing if the new record would violate any unique constraint):

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET status = CASE status
             WHEN 'active' THEN 'not_active'
             ELSE               'active'
             END
WHERE id = ?;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO MyTable (id, status) VALUES (?, 'active');
```